# Getting the whole row from grouped result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here's a sample database table :

```
| ID | ProductID | DateChanged | Price
| 1  | 12        | 2011-11-11  |  93
| 2  | 2         | 2011-11-12  |  12
| 3  | 3         | 2011-11-13  |  25
| 4  | 4         | 2011-11-14  |  17
| 5  | 12        | 2011-11-15  |  97
```

Basically, what I want to happen is get the latest price of grouped by ProductID.

The result should be like this :

```
| ID | ProductID | Price 
| 2  | 2         |  12
| 3  | 3         |  25
| 4  | 4         |  17
| 5  | 12        |  97
```

If you notice, the first row is not there because there is a new price for ProductID 12 which is the row of ID 5.

Basically, it should be something like get ID,ProductID and Price grouped by productID where DateChanged is the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.productid, a.price
from mytable a,
    (select productid, max(datechanged) as maxdatechanged
    from mytable
    group by productid) as b
where a.productid = b.productid and a.datechanged = b.maxdatechanged
```

Comment: Very simple and self-explanatory. Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, ProductId, Price
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, ProductId, Price
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY DateChanged DESC) AS rowNumber
   FROM yourTable
) AS t
WHERE t.rowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ID, ProductID,DateChanged, Price
FROM    myTable  
WHERE   ID IN
(
    SELECT  MAX(ID)
    FROM    myTable 
    GROUP BY ProductID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, ProductId, Price 
from myTable A
where DateChanged >= all 
  (select DateChanged
   from myTable B
   where B.ID = A.ID);
```

Comment: I think my solution is simpler and more intuitive. :-) Select the product and price with the highest value of datechanged among all its own records.